# Query to show total leave hours per month

Tags: sql

I have a `Leave` table as per below:

```
MONTH | NAME | DAY1 | DAY2 | DAY3 | ... | DAY31
------------------------------------------------      
      |      |      |      |      | ... |
```

Columns `DAY1` to `DAY31` keep the number of hours the named person has not been in the office.

I need a query to generate this output:

```
MONTH | NAME | TOTAL_MONTH_HOURS
---------------------------------      
      |      |
```

where `TOTAL_MONTH_HOURS` is sum of all hours in the month; i.e. `DAY1 + DAY2 + ... + DAY30+DAY31`

How should I write this query? Is there any way to escape having to sum all the columns as I did above? I encounter similar problems from time to time where tables get even bigger!

Note: some columns may be `NULL` due to variant month lengths.

Comment: This is not my design; but, I have to work with it anyway! :-)

Comment: Since you designed your database this way, I'm relatively certain you have no idea what @GiantofaLannister ''s `1NF` comment means, so let me help out a bit-- it's "[First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)".

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi questions without a partial attempt often get downvoted, also you have flagged four different database engines.  That would be my guess.

Comment: @Jesse removed all the tags left only sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest, given the current table structure, is simply to do exactly that -

```
Select Month, Name, Day1+Day2+Day3....+Day31 Total_Month_Hours
  From Tbl
```

Now, if it is possible to have NULLs and that being the reason for the question, wrap them with COALESCE.  COALESCE is part of the ANSI SQL99 standard and has support on all major RDBMS ([MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html) [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)).

```
Select Month,
       Name,
       COALESCE(Day1,0)+COALESCE(Day2,0)+...+COALESCE(Day31,0) Total_Month_Hours
  From Tbl
```

Comment: +1  Since the OP removed RDBMS specification, however, I think you'll want `COALESCE` rather than `IFNULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't alter your tables, here:

```
SELECT `month`, `name`, (DAY1+DAY2+DAY3+DAY4+DAY5+DAY6+DAY7+DAY8+DAY9+DAY10+DAY11+DAY12+DAY13+DAY14+DAY15+DAY16+DAY17+DAY18+DAY19+DAY20+DAY21+DAY22+DAY23+DAY24+DAY25+DAY26+DAY27+DAY28+DAY29+DAY30+DAY31) AS `total_month_hours`
FROM `table_name`
```