# Is it better to use entity-arrtibute-value model over storing various different product in single description text column?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I had a conversation with colleague he want to store all arrtibutes as text in column called description and I prefer if we use the EAV model.
What is the pros and cons of each approach?

I think EAV is better for our web application because it will give more precise result over Like that is used for search in text fields.
Also I think it is better when adding new product because for example if user want to add laptop then we know that laptop arrtibutes should be RAM, CPU and HDD so we know what input form to show him/her.

Am I correct? Also Please tell me kindly the pros and cons of each approach

Comment: Nowadays using a `JSON` column is typically more efficient than EAV

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . LOL.  I was about to make exactly the same comment.

Comment: Another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12882531/2469308

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what if json is not an option due to database version?

Comment: You can always upgrade to Postgres ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your suggestions about upgrading, but, if you may please answer me which better approach from the two mentioned approaches and why.